# I see row count difference in Teradata tables between export result and query count

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

Recently I've moved one Teradata test table data to bigquery and I see the row count difference between TD and BQ. As I checked further, I see one of the row value is in "DATE"format instead of "String" because that column is PI column and the data type is VARCHAR. so this row is returning in BQ when I run select but not in TD whereas I see that row when I'm exporting data to excel. I'm really not sure what could be the reason of not showing when I run select statement. Please help me someone to know the reason and also let me know how can I search those problematic data when table is too big. Thanks.
eg : create multiset table Test(a int,b varchar,c varchar,d timestamp(6)) primary index (b);

Data like below in that table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGs0X.png)

Comment: A VarChar has no format, both 'Name' and '8/27/2020' are just strings. You may consider #2 a date, but for the DBMS it's just a series of characters. If Teradata doesn't return this row it's because of a WHERE-condition. Simply run a `select * from tab` to get all rows.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, I'm not using any where condition but that row is skipping when I select * from tab. However that row is exporting to excel and same row I can see it in BQ.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  What do you mean a row shows up when you export to Excel but not when you query the Teradata table? That sounds pretty impossible to me.

Comment: Andrew is right. Maybe there's a linebreak in a VarChar column which confuses Excel or BQ?

Comment: what does mean of linebreak in a varchar column? please provide more details so that I will check on it because there are plenty of tables like that. Thanks.

Comment: `where column like any ('%'||chr(13)||'%', '%'||chr(10)||'%')` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation